# How to echo that the email has been sent?

Tags: php, email

Here it is  a working script in phpmailer. It sends emails from the "Maile" table BUT after the emails are sent I see only email has been sent. If there were 10 emails I get 10x - email has been sent. I would like to it to be shown like this - xxxx@xxxx.xx - email has been sent. How should I do it? Thank You. Here is the code without the part showing the connection with the mail server...

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">




<?php

$con = mysql_connect("XXXX","XXXX","XXXX");
if (!$con){
die("NOT connected: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("test",$con);

    $query  = "SELECT Maile FROM Mailing";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$con);

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){


    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $mail->AddAddress($record["Maile"]);


     if($mail->Send())    
        {                      
        echo 'E-mail has been sent'; 
        }            
    else    
        {           
        echo 'E-mail has not been sent';    
        }


    $mail->ClearAddresses();
    $mail->ClearAttachments();
}

  ?>  

</html>
</head>
```

Comment: What did you try, you've already got `$record["Maile"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood the question entirely but it should just be a case of doing the following:

```
if($mail->Send()) {                      
    echo $record["Maile"] . ' - E-mail has been sent'; 
} else {           
    echo $record["Maile"] . ' - E-mail has not been sent';    
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much BUT how to have it in a table? Should i have a row - Status created? And if yes what then? Thank You

Comment: Do you mean output in a table?

Comment: Yes, I have been working on that for a while I would like to get a table showing 1 - xxx@xxx.xx - sent

Comment: You could echo out a <tr> in the success message, have you got the code you have for the table at the moment? Then I can help a little further :)

Answer (score 1):

Give the following a try, its not tested and its like 00:30 so there may be a mistake

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">




<?php

$con = mysql_connect("XXXX","XXXX","XXXX");
if (!$con){
die("NOT connected: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("test",$con);

$query  = "SELECT Maile FROM Mailing";
$result = mysql_query($query,$con);

echo '<table align="center" style="text-align:center; border:5px solid black;">';
echo '<tr><td>ID</td><td>Maile</td><td>Status</td></tr>'; //You missed ; here

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){


$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAddress($record["Maile"]);


 if($mail->Send())    
    {                      
    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td>'. $record["id"] .'</td>';                
    echo '<td>'.$record["Maile"] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>Success - Email sent</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }            
else    
    {           
    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td>'. $record["id"] .'</td>';           
    echo '<td>'.$record["Maile"] . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>Failed - Email NOT sent</td>';
    echo '</tr>';    
        }


    $mail->ClearAddresses();
    $mail->ClearAttachments();
}
echo '</table>';
  ?>  

</html>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank You it works now... Although I have another problem :) Even if the email is not sent the script echoes - email sent. Why?